SpreadJS 16v refresh from new every time
I'm trying to retrieve user data into the modified spreadsheet but it refreshes from new every time, I'm currently using 16v, this wasn't with 13v.
After calling the function   essIFrame.postMessage(message, ESSurl);     the data is wiped out
I also tried to copy the info into a different input, even bring it from database but the spreadsheet keeps refreshing from new.
I'm expecting to reload the modification that the user does, for example if I write anything into a cell, I'm expecting to see that content but instead I see a new empty spreadsheet
